# Unable to view drive - receive error message

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, drive

I installed GRUB to one of my drives, which caused it not to boot, and showing me "Error 17".

However, I thought about deleting the GRUB directory, as my LiveCD/DVD Ubuntu can not run the GRUB command. (sudo grub)

I had an error message before this one, but I managed to fix it myself.

But it shows this NOW when I try to open in "Files" (it displayed invalid characters on the message when I copied and pasted it, which appears blank here):

```
Sorry, could not display all the contents of “EFI”: 
Error when getting information for file 
'/media/ubuntu/EFI/000 0.$0(': 
Input/output error
```

And I still can't boot because of "Error 17"!

What is happening, and how can I fix it? I can't live without Windows for long...

Also, before I failed at installing GRUB, the drive was labelled as "250 GB Volume", not as "EFI" which is now. I also have more LiveCDs which I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to find a workaround myself!

After attempting to access the drive, do not leave the message box. Then, access it again by another window. I know, it sounds stupid. Trust me, this worked. You can access the drive though this method.